# HTML Required tag playing up

Tags: html, forms

I'm making a form for a task in class and nobody can figure out why the input validation isn't working. The code for the whole form is below. It's specifically the required tag that seems to be causing problems.

```
<form action = "">
                <p>First Name</p>
                <input type = "text" name = "firstname" size = "25" maxlength = "20"></input> <br>
                <p>Last Name</p>
                <input type = "text" name = "lastname" size = "25" maxlength = "20"></input> <br>
                <p>Age</p>
                <input type = "radio" name = "age" value = "<25" checked></input><25
                <input type = "radio" name = "age" value = "25-40" ></input>25-40
                <input type = "radio" name = "age" value = ">40" ></input>>40
                <input type = "radio" name = "age" value = "Rather not say" ></input>Rather not say <br>
                <div style = "float:left">
                    <p>Favourite food</p>
                    <select name = "Favourite food" style = "float:left;">
                        <option value = "1" selected>Italian</option>
                        <option value = "2">Indian</option>
                        <option value = "3">Thai</option>
                        <option value = "4">Chinese</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div style = "float:right">
                    <p>What new country would you like to see on the website?</p>
                    <select name = "newCountry">
                        <option value = "1" selected>Vietnamese</option>
                        <option value = "2">American</option>
                        <option value = "3">French</option>
                        <option value = "4">Spanish</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <br>
                <p style = "clear:both; float:left;">What new cooking technique would you like to see on the website?</p>
                <textarea name = "NewTechnique" rows = "5" cols = "100" maxlength = "500" style = "clear:both;"> </textarea>
                <br>
                <p>Please rate the following from 1 (poor) to 5 (excellent)</p>
                <p>Ease of use</p>
                <input type = "text" name = "easeofuse" size = "25" min = "1" max = "5" required=""></input> <br>
                <p>Quality of information</p>
                <input type = "text" name = "infoquality" size = "25" min = "1" max = "5" required></input> <br>
                <p>Taste of recipies</p>
                <input type = "text" name = "tastes" size = "25" min = "1" max = "5" required = ""></input> <br>
                <p>Permission for my information to be held and used for future developments</p>
                <input type ="radio" name = "permission" value = "1" required></input>Yes
                <input type ="radio" name = "permission" value = "2"></input>No
                <input type = "submit" onclick="alert('form entered')" value = "submit"></input>
            </form>
```

I can't see what the problem is. Is it because the action tag is empty? We've been told to leave it like that.

Edit:Problem has been solved!

Comment: You really should encode your `<` that are not part of HTML tags, so they would become `&lt;`. Also, as James pointed out, you have totally invalid HTML - you don't need `<input></input>` - just `<input />` is ok.

Comment: Fixing [the machine detectable errors](https://validator.nu/) wouldn't do any harm.

Comment: @Stuart — Just `<input>` is fine. No need for extra `/`s.

Comment: That's not even valid HTML. 1. `input`s don't have closing tags; 2. when you want to put `<` in the page text, you need to use entities (`<` becomes `&lt;`). The browser thinks it's opening of a tag otherwise. Form validation seems to work if you fix these two things.

Comment: @Stuart I feel silly that I deleted my comment without seeing that you'd referenced it... Oops. That being said, Nico, it would be better if you added an `onsubmit` to the form rather than an `onclick` to the input. I'm not 100% certain, but it looks like the browser is interpreting the button's `onclick` method and ignoring the form.

Comment: @Quentin -- Me being pedantic, `<input>` is a _void_ element, meaning a SOLIDUS `/` is allowed, even if it is redundant :)

Comment: @Stuart — I said "no need" not that they are forbidden

Comment: @Quentin I know - hence me saying "Me being pedantic"! ;)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To get the form `required` fields to work, I've replaced the `onclick` with `onsubmit` inside the `form` tag. I've also cleaned up whatever HTML oddities I found after a quick skim (I've probably missed a few).

```html
<form onsubmit='alert("ya done clicked")'>
  <p>First Name</p>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" size="25" maxlength="20"> <br>
  <p>Last Name</p>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" size="25" maxlength="20"> <br>
  <p>Age</p>
  <input type="radio" name="age" value="&lt;25" checked>&lt;25
  <input type="radio" name="age" value="25-40">25-40
  <input type="radio" name="age" value=">40">&gt;40
  <input type="radio" name="age" value="Rather not say">Rather not say <br>
  <div style="float:left">
    <p>Favourite food</p>
    <select name="Favourite food" style="float:left;">
      <option value="1" selected>Italian</option>
      <option value="2">Indian</option>
      <option value="3">Thai</option>
      <option value="4">Chinese</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div style="float:right">
    <p>What new country would you like to see on the website?</p>
    <select name="newCountry">
      <option value="1" selected>Vietnamese</option>
      <option value="2">American</option>
      <option value="3">French</option>
      <option value="4">Spanish</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <br>
  <p style="clear:both; float:left;">What new cooking technique would you like to see on the website?</p>
  <textarea name="NewTechnique" rows="5" cols="100" maxlength="500" style="clear:both;"> </textarea>
  <br>
  <p>Please rate the following from 1 (poor) to 5 (excellent)</p>
  <p>Ease of use</p>
  <input type="text" name="easeofuse" size="25" min="1" max="5" required> <br>
  <p>Quality of information</p>
  <input type="text" name="infoquality" size="25" min="1" max="5" required> <br>
  <p>Taste of recipies</p>
  <input type="text" name="tastes" size="25" min="1" max="5" required> <br>
  <p>Permission for my information to be held and used for future developments</p>
  <input type="radio" name="permission" value="1" required>Yes
  <input type="radio" name="permission" value="2">No
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I'd be interested in getting some feedback on what about this answer is not useful. It solves the problem at hand, namely that the form validation wasn't working, while keeping in an alert like OP's original snippet had.

Comment: You're welcome! Please accept this answer to let others know that this problem has been solved.